# PowerQuery - Count number of unique instances of data in aggregated / grouped data

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have the following data of events by players in a game.  Using this data I would like to know how many times each player played for their team across the data set. When I group the data, I count the number of instances of the player column but that can be too high ie they have 3 events in a game but that should only count as them having played once. I can't find a way to get if they played or not per match and not all their events when grouping.

Desired result would be :

| Team | Player | No of Times Played |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | P1 | 3 |
| AAA | P2 | 2 |

As P1 played on 1/1, 1/2 and 1/4)
As P2 only played on 1/1 and 1/2 and not 1/4)

Here is the source data:

| Team | Date | Player | Event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 1/1/23 | P1 | Shoot |
| AAA | 1/1/23 | P2 | Miss |
| AAA | 1/1/23 | P1 | Pass |
| AAA | 1/1/23 | P3 | Score |
| AAA | 1/1/23 | P5 | Miss |
| AAA | 1/1/23 | P1 | Shoot |
| AAA | 1/2/23 | P6 | Shoot |
| AAA | 1/2/23 | P1 | Miss |
| AAA | 1/2/23 | P3 | Pass |
| AAA | 1/2/23 | P4 | Miss |
| AAA | 1/2/23 | P7 | Miss |
| AAA | 1/2/23 | P1 | Shoot |
| AAA | 1/4/23 | P1 | Score |
| AAA | 1/4/23 | P2 | Shoot |
| AAA | 1/4/23 | P4 | Miss |
| BBB | 1/1/23 | P1 | Miss |
| BBB | 1/1/23 | P3 | Miss |
| BBB | 1/1/23 | P1 | Pass |
| BBB | 1/1/23 | P6 | Score |
| BBB | 1/3/23 | P5 | Miss |
| BBB | 1/3/23 | P3 | Shoot |
| BBB | 1/3/23 | P2 | Shoot |
| BBB | 1/4/23 | P1 | Score |
| BBB | 1/4/23 | P3 | Pass |

Group by but counts the number of rows, not unique instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a group and replace the code as follows:

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Team", "Player"}, {{"Count", each List.Count( List.Distinct( _[Date])) , Int64.Type}})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Click select the Team, Date and Player columns, right click, remove duplicates

Click select the Team and Player columns, right click group by, and use defaults

[image]

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source, {"Team", "Player", "Date"}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Duplicates", {"Team", "Player"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Nice one horseyride!